# How to select all similar files in an directory

Tags: macos, finder

If I want to view images I made with my camera using Preview, I have to select all files separately. Because when I select all files (cmd + a) all the videos I made get selected (and opened in Quicktime) too.

So I was wondering how I can select only the images in a certain directory?

Comment: Interested to see all the different ways people suggest you limit the view to certain types. There are many.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the Search feature in Finder to limit the view in a specific folder to search criteria that matches what's in the search field. One of the criteria you can search on is `kind`. In the screen shot below I start typing `kind:jpeg` in the search field and you see that Finder presents me with a drop down list that includes `JPEG Image`. I select this from the list and I'll see only files of that kind. To limit the filter to just this folder I make sure the **Downloads** view is clicked on the `Search:` area just about the list of files instead of **This Mac**.

Once you've searched and filtered your view this way, you can select all to perform an operation on files that match that search.

[image: Searching by Kind]

Comment: Is it possible to search for multiple "kinds" with this approach?

Comment: Yes and no. There are broader kinds you can use. Try: `kind:image` to see all image files. Or `kind:movie` to see a video files. There's a OR operator, `|`, for searches but it doesn't seem to work with the `kind:` filter.

Comment: Thanks, I also tried the, | ,operator and found no success with "kind:". Thanks for the tip on "kind:image"

Answer (score 2):

If all of the images have the same extension the following command (when run in Terminal.app) will search your directory for files with that specific extension and open them in Preview.

```
find /yourdir -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec open -a /Applications/Preview.app {} \;
```

If you want to search through multiple directories and not stop at the root directory (in this case "yourdir" you can remove the "-maxdepth 1" portion.

**If you want to search for multiple file extensions (jpg and tif) use the following command.**

```
find /yourdir -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -name '*.jpg' -o -name '*.tif' \) -exec open -a /Applications/Preview.app {} \;
```

Comment: That seems a bit overkill.  Your first example can be achieved with `open *.jpg`, assuming Preview is the default for .jpg files - if not, then `/Applications/Preview.app *.jpg` should also work.  If you want to search the subdirectories, you'd need a find as you suggest.  Likewise, for multiple file extensions, `open *.jpg *.tif` should work.

Comment: Very true. Normally I would not include the "open -a /Applications/Preview.app" and instead simply execute the open command, but not knowing everything on martin's system I felt it may be best to declare Preview as the application to open the images in. :)